# Error with Google Maps JavaScript API >= 3.28 and Apache Flex 4 StageWebView

Tags: google-maps, apache-flex, google-maps-api-3, air, stagewebview

Hi we're using Google Maps JavaScript Library inside of an Apache AIR WindowedApplications with Flex 4.14.1 and AIR 18.

The Google Map lives inside a HTML Page that we integrate in our AIR Application with Flex StageWebView (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html).

I've created a minimalistic working example to reproduce the problem.

**Flex:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       addedToStage="addedToStageHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected var stageWebView:StageWebView;

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            stageWebView = new StageWebView();
            stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
            stageWebView.stage = stage;
            stageWebView.loadURL("file:\\C:/work/flex/MapTest/src/assets/googlemap.html");
            stageWebView.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onWebViewError);
        }

        private static function onWebViewError(ev:Event):void
        {
            trace('Error' + ev);
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            if (stageWebView)
                stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

**HTML-File included as file:\\C:/work/flex/MapTest/src/assets/googlemap.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
        });

      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see we're always using the current major release of google maps (version attribute v=3): `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap" async defer></script>`

On 16th of may google released version 3.28 as major release. Since then we get the following error during map initialization inside the StageWebView:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'a.lat' [undefined] is not a function.
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 107
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 122
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 41
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 105
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/28/18/intl/de_ALL/map.js : 61
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 93
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 107
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 53
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 107
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 55
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 107
 at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap : 32
```

Since we did not change the Flex maps integration for several years, the initialization process of the google Map version >= 3.28 must break the map to load inside of the StageWebView.

What we've tried so far:

- Directly open the HTML Page in different Browsers => worked (see example here)
- Update to the most recent Flex and AIR versions (4.16 and AIR 25) => no success
- Downgrade to Google Map v 3.27 (Frozen) => current solution, but will break as soon as v 3.29 becomes major release
- Check the release notes => no breaking changes
- Change Google Maps init code to use lat/lng Object => no success
- Write lat/lng attribute in google Maps init code as Strings => no success

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: What's "s.th."?

Comment: Hi Brian. That's the big question. It might be a change in the initialization code of the google map library. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I meant I don't know what the letters "s.th." mean.

Comment: With s.th. i mean something ;)

Comment: Today we've updated our html file to use the current experimental version (3.29.9a) of google maps. This version fixes our issue!
The map loads successfully without any errors...